# NSString formatting from sentence like to numbered

Tags: ios, iphone, c

My nsstring is like :

```
1)I m a good boy.2)I read in School.3)I play cricket.
```

How to make it look like below if i m making it equal to text property of label .

```
1)I m a good boy.
2)I read in School.
3)I play cricket.
```

Comment: I mean one sentence in a line . new sentence in another line . Actually this is response from server I m getting . .

Comment: What can you rely on? Single sentence? Single full stop? Numbers and brackets? What are the rules?

Comment: Full stop i cant rely on . I want if 1) /2) are there , i need to represent in point like order . Response can be a sentence as well . In that case i dont want to do anything . So if there are numbers as i mentioned , i need to put all of them in separate line

Comment: i did :  howToUse=[howToUse stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@".\n"];

Comment: but output is like ....1)I m a good boy.
                            2)I read in School.
                            3)I play cricket.

Answer (score 0):

Simply just use this :

```
NSString* string = @"1)I m a good boy.2)I read in School.3)I play cricket.";
Label.numberOfLines = 0 ;
[Label sizeToFit];
Label.text = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@".\n"] ;
```

Comment: Use this full code then see the output . I just missed out two lines . Now its complete .

Comment: but whats happening , that after writing first sentence 2) is coming on next line but after padding some spaces... 2) not starting from same value of origin.x .... 3) is coming below 2) ... 1) is not aligned with them .. both 2) and 3)  coming after padding spaces initially

Comment: There might be the case that your string is something like this :
string = @"1)I m a good boy. 2)I read in School. 3)I play cricket." 
Here is space after '.' which is the cause of you output .

Comment: Remove that space after '.'
It will gonna help you .

Answer (score 0):

This will give you array of strings using separation based on .

```
NSArray *stringArray = [string componentsSeparatedByString: @"."];
```

You can then append . and \n to each string from array. And can create your final string.

0-> 1)I m a good boy

1-> 2)I read in School

2-> 3)I play cricket.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using `NSScanner` and the `scanUpToCharactersFromSet:intoString:`. Where the set you are scanning to is all numbers and bracket characters. When you get a match, you need to check for the existence of the bracket (you may have just found a number in the middle of the sentence).

Once you have found the sentence content (bear in mind you may need to concatenate parts) you can build your result string with, as desired, carriage returns and removal of padding spaces (`stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:`).